# accessing javascript local vars in a custom on-event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble accessing local variables and functions from a custom 'on' event.

The following code returns null for oc and returns the data correctly.

```
var oc = "localvar";
$(frm).on('mycb',function(data){
  console.log(data);
  console.log(oc); 
});
```

How can I access local variables and functions from within the callback ?

Comment: Make sure you put the semi-colon after `var oc = "localvar";`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, there is a semicolon after, but I am unable to access any functions or variables that are not inherited from the callback data

Comment: In which context is oc defined? Are you sure that it is not defined within some other function definition?

Comment: `console.log(oc);` should work fine. Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ that recreates the issue.

Comment: @FelixKling Why not the built in stack snippet..? :)

Comment: @TJ: I haven't fully arrived in the future yet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, but if it isn't, then you could pass it in `data` as per

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

which you can access through `event.data`

```
var oc = "localvar"
$(frm).on('mycb', { oc : oc }, function(data){
   console.log(data);
   console.log(data.oc); // access it here 
});
```

Comment: @crankshaft glad to have helped you :)